# Why do I get PLS-00302: component must be declared when it exists?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am using Oracle 10.2.

I am working in some scripts to move some ORACLE Objects from one SCHEMA (S1) to another (S2). 
I am creating the functions with DBA role.
When moved, one of my functions becomes invalid, but I don't understand why.
Its code goes along these lines:

**MY_FUNC**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION S2."MY_FUNC" RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   something VARCHAR2;
   othervar VARCHAR2 (50):= 'TEST';   
BEGIN
   something := S2.MY_FUNC2();
    /*some code*/
    return othervar;
END;
/
```

If I use `MY_FUNC2` without the schema, It works:
**`something := MY_FUNC2();`** instead of  **`something := S2.MY_FUNC2();`**

**My_FUNC2**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION S2."MY_FUNC2" RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
       something BOOLEAN;
       othervar VARCHAR2 (50) := 'TEST2';           
    BEGIN
       /*some code*/
        return othervar;
    END;
    /
```

MY_FUNC2 has a synonym like this:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM "MY_FUNC2" FOR "S2"."MY_FUNC2"
```

`MY_FUNC` compiles with errors:

> PLS-00302: component 'MY_FUNC2' must be declared

I don't understand why I am getting this error, when my functions were in the other schema (S1) they had exactly the same structure and the synonym was created exactly the same (but pointing to S1) and `MY_FUNC` compiled fine.

I didn't create this functions and synonym originally. Is it possible that I am missing some privileges in S2, so `MY_FUNC` can work properly?

Comment: are you calling the function from s1 or s2?

Comment: If you make the call from s1, you need to give grant execute privilege on s2.MY_FUNC2 to s1.

Comment: as far as i understand this is not about call, it doesn't even compile. So just to make sure, because it is not clear from your question. Are you logged as sys or s2? You first created  MY_FUNC2, then created public synonym, and then MY_FUNC? IF you are SYS or S2 with create public synonym privilege and did it in this order there is no reason not to compile (except that my_func has declaration of varchar2; without precision)

Comment: @Aramillo everything is in S2, and I am logged with DBA Role. The issue was described bellow by Alex.

Comment: ANOTHER SOLUTION: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834596/telling-me-my-stored-procedure-isnt-declared

Comment: Me:  "This answer doesn't apply to my database; I know I wouldn't create a table with the same name as the schema."
Me five minutes later:  "Well, dang, I have a table in there with the same name as the schema.  How'd that happen?"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get that error if you have an object with the same name as the schema. For example:

```
create sequence s2;

begin
  s2.a;
end;
/

ORA-06550: line 2, column 6:
PLS-00302: component 'A' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

When you refer to `S2.MY_FUNC2` the object name is being resolved so it doesn't try to evaluate S2 as a schema name. When you just call it as `MY_FUNC2` there is no confusion, so it works.

The documentation [explains name resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_dependencies.htm#i3136). The first piece of the qualified object name - S2 here - is evaluated as an object on the current schema before it is evaluated as a different schema.

It might not be a sequence; other objects can cause the same error. You can check for the existence of objects with the same name by querying the data dictionary.

```
select owner, object_type, object_name
from all_objects
where object_name = 'S2';
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! This seems to make sense, they have a View with the same name than the Schema. Is there a way to  make Oracle interpret S2 as a schema and not as the View?

Comment: @Dzyann - not according to those search rules. Why do you have it qualified at all though; if you're referring to something in the same schema there's no real benefit to prefixing everything with the schema name?

Comment: Well initially I just couldn't understand why this worked in one schema and not the other. Also after understanding the issue, I realize this will happen from other schemas as well. Calling MY_FUNC2 from S1 fails because Oracle finds first the SYNONYM to the S2 View, instead of the S2 schema. Basically, since I can't force oracle to interpret S2 as an schema, I think the way to go is to change the name of the S2 View and its PUBLIC SYNONYM.

Comment: Probably; having conflicting identifiers is going to cause confusion at best. Some people like to use Hungarian notation or variants, which would tend to avoid this sort of thing, but other people despise it, and the limit on identifier length can make it awkward anyway. (S2 doesn't seem very descriptive for a view name though, or for a schema name, but not always under our control...)

Comment: Thanks again, you have been a lot of help. S2 is not the real name, I just used that to simplify my post, the real name is good actually, I am trying to think of a nice short alternative.

Comment: Tom Kyte, Oracle's tech guru, says to avoid public synonyms to avoid a variety of problems, such as this one.

Answer (score 13):

I came here because I had the same problem. 
What was the problem for me was that the procedure was defined in the package body, but not in the package header. 
I was executing my function with a lose BEGIN END statement.

Comment: Bless you :) I had the same problem, forgot the package SPEC

Comment: i encountered the same situation, but in a legacy code. The procedure was meant to be a local one, invisible to the outside world. The solution was to look for some parent procedure that would call it . This time, the parent procedure is declared in the header