# Issue with PL/SQL function returns TYPE object

Tags: oracle, plsql

Cannot run very basic function that returns TYPE object.

TYPE, FUNCTION and PL/SQL block belong to same schema. Executed by schema owner. Used Oracle 12C.

I just have no even a clue what is going on wrong...

Have TYPE:

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TYPE RAW_PRODUCT_T AS OBJECT 
(
    id              INT,
    brand           VARCHAR2(300),
    catalog_number  VARCHAR2(300)
)
```

Have FUNCTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NEXT_NOT_LOADED_RAW_PRODUCT RETURN RAW_PRODUCT_T AS
BEGIN
    RETURN raw_product_t(1, 'x', 'z');
END NEXT_NOT_LOADED_RAW_PRODUCT;
```

Have PL/SQL code block:

```
DECLARE
    v_Return PRODUCTS.RAW_PRODUCT_T;
BEGIN
    v_Return := NEXT_NOT_LOADED_RAW_PRODUCT();
END;
/
```

Have error message:

```
Error starting at line : 40 in command -
DECLARE
    v_Return PRODUCTS.RAW_PRODUCT_T;
BEGIN
    v_Return := NEXT_NOT_LOADED_RAW_PRODUCT();
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 23:
PLS-00302: component 'RAW_PRODUCT_T' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 14:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

UPDATE

Now I see issue was in line `v_Return PRODUCTS.RAW_PRODUCT_T;`. When it replaced with `v_Return RAW_PRODUCT_T;` it works. But why it does not work with prefix `PRODUCTS.`?? I guess it should just work both ways.

Comment: What is `PRODUCTS`? Is that the schema the type and function are under; and that you're running the anonymous block as? And, assuming that is the case - do you have a package in that schema that is also called `PRODUCTS`? I think you're seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28708678/266304).

Comment: Yes, `PRODUCTS` is schema name. Yes, anonymous block running in that schema. I do not have package `PRODUCTS`. Actually there are no any packages.

Comment: Are there objects of any kind - does `select object_type from user_objects where object_name = 'PRODUCTS'` return anything?

Comment: YES, I have a table with name 'PRODUCTS'.

Comment: I use suffixes like _tp, _fn, _pr, etc for all kinds of staff in database. But I do not use any suffixes for schema names and table names. It caught me.

Comment: Yes, it can be any object; the linked one was from a view, but happens with tables and sequences etc. Not sure why I originally only asked about packages. It's down to name resolution, anyway.