# PLSQL Error - Error in Executing Procedure CallableStatementCallback;

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc

I am trying to invoke the stored procedure below from my Java Code.

```java
public void runProcedure(String accountId, String date, String receiverId, int seqNo) {
        final SimpleJdbcCall transactionCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.jdbcTemplate)
                .withSchemaName("CUSTOM")
                .withProcedureName("PROC_REPORT_STATEMENT");

        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("accountId", accountId)
                .addValue("sdate", date)
                .addValue("recvID", receiverId)
                .addValue("seqNo", seqNo);
        transactionCall.execute(in);
    }
```

If executed on Toad with user `USER1` it works as expected.

However, using the same user in my Java code returns the error below

> Error in Executing Procedure CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call CUSTOM.PROC_REPORT_STATEMENT(?, ?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CUSTOM.PROC_REPORT_STATEMENT(
accountId IN VARCHAR2,
sdate IN DATE,
recvID IN VARCHAR2,
seqNo IN NUMBER
) AS
....
```

I have carried out all that was requested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834596/pls-00302-telling-me-my-stored-procedure-isnt-declared) and still not able to find a solution.

I have no clue what to do next

Comment: IDK anything about spring, but there must be a way like in hibernate to enable sql-level tracing.  turn that on and see what the actual SQL statement that is being executed is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from the inner exception that it was failing because of the error below:

`ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large ORA-06512`

The culprit: One of the variables

`openbal             NUMBER (10,2);`

A query in the procedure was trying to fetch a value greater than the variable declared to hold the fetched result

I had to change it to something larger.

`openbal             NUMBER (25,2);`

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your CUSTOM.PROC_REPORT_STATEMENT procedure valid?
2. In the Java code you wrote .addValue("accountId", accountId) but the parameter name in the stored procedure is accounted. Isn't it a problem?

Comment: Thank you Kapitany, the procedure is valid and the mistake in the parameter was made while putting up the question here